# Socket barcode scanner sdk crashing on reloading ViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, socketscan

I seem to be having some issues using the Socket ScanAPI in a multipurpose app. I'm using the single entry swift example code on GitHub, and the socket scanner and code works flawlessly when I present the VC used for scanning the first time.

Initialization is like the example code, except I initialize scanApiHelpher with ScanApiHelper() and not the shared version:

```
    var scanApiHelper = ScanApiHelper() 
scanApiHelperConsumer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("onScanApiHelperConsumer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        scanApiHelper.pushDelegate(self)
        scanApiHelper.open()
```

The problem comes when I dismiss the VC, then present it again, I get a crash in sktscanapilistenerthread at 0x1005705c8:

```
0x1005705b4 <+1332>: bl     0x10058ab88               ; CSktScanAPI::NotifyError at CSktScanAPI.cpp:4639
    0x1005705b8 <+1336>: adrp   x8, 515
    0x1005705bc <+1340>: ldr    x1, [x8, #3296]
    0x1005705c0 <+1344>: ldr    x0, [sp, #8]
    0x1005705c4 <+1348>: bl     0x10062b338               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x1005705c8 <+1352>: add    x0, sp, #48               ; =48 
    0x1005705cc <+1356>: bl     0x100563308               ; CSktList::~CSktList at SktList.cpp:29
    0x1005705d0 <+1360>: add    x0, sp, #312              ; =312 
    0x1005705d4 <+1364>: bl     0x10057fa68               ; SktAccessoryEnumerator::~SktAccessoryEnumerator at SktAccessoryEnumerator.mm:45
```

Does the SDK start up a background thread when the helper object is initialized, and so reinitializing this is causing a crash? i.e. must the helper object initialization take place in the root VC?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something on the docs but it seems that for any use of the scanner API which involves dismissing a VC which uses the API, the sharedhelper object is required since it's impossible to initialize a ScanApiHelper var more than once (it creates a background thread on init).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement all the delegate functions so that the API can call them. Even if they are empty the API will call them and if they are not present it will crash.

```
// MARK: SocketScanAPI methods
    @objc func onScanApiHelperConsumer(){

        if(!(scanApiHelper?.isScanApiOpen())!) {
            scanApiHelper?.open()
        }
        scanApiHelper?.doScanApiReceive()
    }

    public func onDeviceArrival(_ result: SKTRESULT, device deviceInfo: DeviceInfo!) {
        print("Main view device arrival:\(deviceInfo.getName() as String)")
    }

    public func onDeviceRemoval(_ deviceRemoved: DeviceInfo!) {
        print("Main view device removal:\(deviceRemoved.getName() as String)")
    }

    public func onDecodedDataResult(_ result: Int, device: DeviceInfo!, decodedData: ISktScanDecodedData!) {
        if result==ESKT_NOERROR {
            let rawData = decodedData.getData()
            let rawDataSize = decodedData.getSize()
            let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(rawData!), count: Int(rawDataSize))
            //print("Size: \(rawDataSize)")
            //print("data: \(data)")
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            let string = str! as String
            print("Decoded Data \(string)")
            NSLog("Decoded Data %@", string)
        }
    }

    public func onError(_ result: SKTRESULT) {
        print("Receive a ScanApi error: \(result)")
    }

    public func onErrorRetrievingScanObject(_ result: SKTRESULT) {
        print("Receive a ScanApi error while retrieving a ScanObject: \(result)")
    }

    public func onScanApiInitializeComplete(_ result: SKTRESULT) {
        print("Result of ScanAPI initialization: \(result)")
    }

    @objc public func onScanApiTerminated() {
        print("ScanAPI has terminated")
    }
```